# Where does "AttributeError: 'VendorAlias' object has no attribute 'find_spec'" come from?

Tags: python, django, pytest, python-3.10

I'm currently trying to update a larger codebase from Python 3.8 to Python 3.11. I use `pyenv` to manage my Python versions and `poetry` to manage my dependencies:

```
pyenv local 3.11.3
poetry update
```

When I run `pytest` I immediately get:

```
python -m pytest  -n 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1074, in _find_spec
AttributeError: 'VendorAlias' object has no attribute 'find_spec'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/martin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web-backend-4tJQ0X3K-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 58, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module("%s.%s" % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/home/martin/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1140, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1076, in _find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1049, in _find_spec_legacy
ImportWarning: VendorAlias.find_spec() not found; falling back to find_module()

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1074, in _find_spec
AttributeError: 'VendorAlias' object has no attribute 'find_spec'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/home/martin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web-backend-4tJQ0X3K-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytest/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    raise SystemExit(pytest.console_main())
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/martin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web-backend-4tJQ0X3K-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 189, in console_main
    code = main()
           ^^^^^^
  File "/home/martin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web-backend-4tJQ0X3K-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 147, in main
    config = _prepareconfig(args, plugins)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/martin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web-backend-4tJQ0X3K-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 328, in _prepareconfig
    config = pluginmanager.hook.pytest_cmdline_parse(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/martin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web-backend-4tJQ0X3K-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 265, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/martin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web-backend-4tJQ0X3K-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 80, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/martin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web-backend-4tJQ0X3K-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 55, in _multicall
    gen.send(outcome)
  File "/home/martin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web-backend-4tJQ0X3K-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/helpconfig.py", line 103, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    config: Config = outcome.get_result()
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/martin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web-backend-4tJQ0X3K-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_result.py", line 60, in get_result
    raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
  File "/home/martin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web-backend-4tJQ0X3K-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 39, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/martin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web-backend-4tJQ0X3K-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 1067, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    self.parse(args)
  File "/home/martin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web-backend-4tJQ0X3K-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 1354, in parse
    self._preparse(args, addopts=addopts)
  File "/home/martin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web-backend-4tJQ0X3K-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 1256, in _preparse
    self.hook.pytest_load_initial_conftests(
  File "/home/martin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web-backend-4tJQ0X3K-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 265, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/martin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web-backend-4tJQ0X3K-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 80, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/martin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web-backend-4tJQ0X3K-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 60, in _multicall
    return outcome.get_result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/martin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web-backend-4tJQ0X3K-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_result.py", line 60, in get_result
    raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
  File "/home/martin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web-backend-4tJQ0X3K-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 39, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/martin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web-backend-4tJQ0X3K-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytest_django/plugin.py", line 353, in pytest_load_initial_conftests
    _setup_django()
  File "/home/martin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web-backend-4tJQ0X3K-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytest_django/plugin.py", line 236, in _setup_django
    django.setup()
  File "/home/martin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web-backend-4tJQ0X3K-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/martin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web-backend-4tJQ0X3K-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/home/martin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web-backend-4tJQ0X3K-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 27, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/home/martin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web-backend-4tJQ0X3K-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 50, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules("admin", register_to=site)
  File "/home/martin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web-backend-4tJQ0X3K-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 70, in autodiscover_modules
    if module_has_submodule(app_config.module, module_to_search):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/martin/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web-backend-4tJQ0X3K-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 85, in module_has_submodule
    return importlib_find(full_module_name, package_path) is not None
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib.util>", line 103, in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1076, in _find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1049, in _find_spec_legacy
ImportWarning: VendorAlias.find_spec() not found; falling back to find_module()
```

I have no clue where that comes from.

When I uninstall `pytest-django`, then `pytest` at least starts. However, in a related project everything works fine - and that includes `pytest-djanog` in the same version.

The upgrade to Python 3.9 worked, but to 3.10 (and 3.11) it failed.

How can I investigate that issue?

Answer (score 0):

The dependency [Advocate](https://github.com/JordanMilne/Advocate) seems to be the reason. I don't know how it makes pytest fail like that - something related to Python 2 compatibility. Removing it did the trick.

I found it by `grep`-ing the virtual environment for `VendorAlias`